# spark do not show all content in line

Tags: apache-spark

I have a data frame with content

```
scala> true_nomar.show(1)
+--------+--------------+--------------------+------+------+--------------------+
|category|topicUpPredict|               topic|ciTrue|upTrue|              normal|
+--------+--------------+--------------------+------+------+--------------------+
|the_thao|      the_thao|[the_thao, the_gioi]|  true|  true| Khi các mục sư m...|
+--------+--------------+--------------------+------+------+--------------------+
only showing top 1 row
```

but when i show all, the content of column **normal** is not full text, another columns has no content

```
scala> true_nomar.show(1,false)
+--------+--------------+--------------------+------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|category|topicUpPredict|topic               |ciTrue|upTrue|normal                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              |
+--------+--------------+--------------------+------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
Thích thú trước hai vị học trò đặc biệt này, ông Eriksson nói: "Bóng đá cần nhiều người như là hai vị mục sư Charles và Tim để tạo cho trẻ em thật nhiều cơ hội đến với bóng đá”. Thậm chí Geoff Hurst, cựu ngôi sa|ổi lại, hai mục sư Crosland và Smith cùng các con chiên sẽ cầu nguyện cho đội tuyển Anh trong VCK World Cup 2006 mà trước mắt là cầu nguyện cho chấn thương của tiền đạo Michael Owen sớm hồi phục. 
+--------+--------------+--------------------+------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
only showing top 1 row
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most likely due to one or more carriage return (CR) symbols (`\r` in Scala string literals) embedded somewhere in the text. When a CR is encountered, the terminal moves the caret to the beginning of the line, which messes up the output:

```scala
scala> "123\r456"
4560: String = 123
```

Here, the output should be `res0: String = 123...`, but the caret position gets reset after `123` and `456` overwrites `res`. The same happens when a dataframe is printed:

```scala
scala> Seq(("baz", "foofoofoo\rbarbar")).toDF("cat", "normal").show(false)
+---+----------------+
|cat|normal          |
+---+----------------+
barbar|ofoofoo
+---+----------------+
```

If you look closer at your output, you'll find the closing `|`, so it is full text, just garbled:

```
--------------------

--------------------
 cựu ngôi sa|ổi lại,
--------------------
            ^
            ^
   end of "normal" column
```

Use `regexp_replace($"normal", "\r", "\\\\r")` to replace all CRs with the escaped representation `\r`:

```scala
scala> val df = Seq(("baz", "foofoofoo\rbarbar")).toDF("cat", "normal")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [cat: string, normal: string]

scala> df.show(false)
+---+----------------+
|cat|normal          |
+---+----------------+
barbar|ofoofoo
+---+----------------+


scala> df.withColumn("normal", regexp_replace($"normal", "\r", "\\\\r")).show(false)
+---+-----------------+
|cat|normal           |
+---+-----------------+
|baz|foofoofoo\rbarbar|
+---+-----------------+
```

Comment: thanks, i tried to remove \n, not  \r.